# Does SQL Server support health check?

Tags: sql-server

I have a few SQL Server 2012 instance. And I'd like to perform a regular health check on this instance. I wonder whether SQL server has any default health check endpoint I can use. Ideally, I'd like to add the check on my application server to check the health response from SQL Server every 10 seconds. And it will send me an alert if it is unhealthy.

Comment: Services such as Amazon's RDS (relational database service) make it easy to implement things like a health check.  You might want to look into using AWS or another similar service.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** - 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, and soon 2019 ....

Comment: What kind of health check are you looking at ? Anyway `10 seconds` is way too frequent. Here is a ref https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/john_daskalakis/2013/12/09/how-to-do-a-quick-sql-server-healthcheck/  just perform a search and you will get lots of hits

Comment: I am looking for a very light heath checks to make sure SQL Server is alive. It can be something like `ping`.